# Knockout - groupable array

Tags: knockout.js, group-by, ko.observablearray

From the tutorial, I am trying to understand this promising framework.
My question is how to extract some data from an observable array (filter)?
I found a similar quesion here :
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877301/knockoutjs-observablearray-data-grouping)

But I don't know how to implement it.
here is the test :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiminox/gbWmm/1/)

HTML code:

```
<h2>Your seat reservations (<span data-bind="text: seats().length"></span>)</h2>
<h4>
Distribution by meal type:
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: availableMeals">
                <th><span data-bind="text: mealName"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: availableMeals">
                <td>???</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h4>
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat, enable: seats().length < 7">Reserve another seat</button>

<h3 data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
    Total surcharge: $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
```

JS code :

```
// extend from the link to the similar question from stackoverflow:
ko.observableArray.fn.distinct = function(prop) {
    var target = this;
    target.index = {};
    target.index[prop] = ko.observable({});    
    //Group by already set up, bail out.
    if (target.index && target.index[prop]) return target;
    ko.computed(function() {
        //rebuild index
        var propIndex = {};

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(target(), function(item) {
            var key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[prop]);
            if (key) {
                propIndex[key] = propIndex[key] || [];
                propIndex[key].push(item);            
            }
        });   

        target.index[prop](propIndex);
    });

    return target;
};

// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });    
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[1]),
        new SeatReservation("John", self.availableMeals[1]),
        new SeatReservation("Frank", self.availableMeals[1]),
        new SeatReservation("Evan", self.availableMeals[2])
    ]);

    // Computed data
    self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < self.seats().length; i++)
           total += self.seats()[i].meal().price;
       return total;
    });    

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
    self.removeSeat = function(seat) { self.seats.remove(seat) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

I worked from the KO tutorial : the pb is I want to display a distribution of customers by meal types?

Comment: Wups, I had an answer but deleted it, after your edits I now see you want a "distribution", that is: an aggregate (my answer didn't account for that).

Comment: You question is somewhat unclear.. what do you mean on "distribution of customers by meal types"  something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3FHEK/1/?

Comment: something like that but that means we have to do it manually right? if yes, maybe you can post your answer? Then other people will use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box Knockout doesn't provide any "groupable array".

However Knockout comes [with some utility functions](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) like:

- `ko.utils.arrayForEach`
- `ko.utils.arrayFilter`

which can help you to build your own custom grouping by hand.

So here is a how sample `mealDistribution` implementation could look like:

```
self.mealDistribution = ko.computed(function () {
        var seatCount = self.seats().length;
        var result = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.availableMeals, function (meal) {
            var mealCount = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.seats(), function (item) {
                return item.meal() == meal}).length;
            result.push(mealCount / seatCount);

        });
        return result;
    });
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FHEK/1/).

If you want to have some more sophisticated array handling functions you should checkout the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library which has some really nice functions like `groupBy`, `countBy`

Comment: +1 for Underscore.js. I knew about it, but I was not using it in my project until I really needed. The advantage of using libraries like underscore.js or linq.js (for those who is used to LINQ in .net) is that functions like groupby and countby are tested and likely are more efficient than the custom ones that you can write using ko.utils.